# Form OnDeactivate - need to determine which is the new Activated control

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have the code which shows a search form for a specific DBGrid which is placed in *another* form (the caller Form of `TSearchGridForm`):

```
procedure TSearchGridForm.FormDeactivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // Pseudo
  if NewActiveControl <> CallerForm.DBGrid then
    Close;
end;
```

The `TSearchGridForm` is activated by the caller form with `.Show` (not Modal) and when it is deactivated I want to close/hide it only if the new active control <> `CallerForm.DBGrid`.

Only if the user clicked on `DBGrid` on the caller form the search form should remain visible, otherwise I need to close it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to find the new active control (if so on which form?) or the new active form, which Screen.ActiveForm should tell you.

Comment: @MartynA, The active control of the opener form that opens `TSearchGridForm` (The grid is placed in that opener form).

Comment: Not sure I follow, but see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Delphi's `TScreen` object has events OnActiveControlChange and OnActiveFormChange.  You can set up event handlers for these to monitor changes and react to them.

See the D7 Online Help for more info. There are Delphi VCL code examples of using both events.

Comment: exactly what I needed. Thanks!